# Remove new tab and close tab buttons in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, gui

I always use ctrl + T to open a new tab, so I have no need for the new tab button. I'd also like to remove the close tab buttons since I always close tabs with ctrl + W.

Comment: You cannot just change a setting to achieve this. However, there is an alternative, as Google open-sourced the software. You could dive into the open-source version, the Chromium project, and modify the code to disable the display of these buttons. You need some programming skills to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there seems to be no way to prevent close button from showing up ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889044/any-way-to-remove-x-button-from-chrome-tabs)), but a way to greatly shrink the horizontal space used by tab title is to pin it (this will remove both title and remove button).

Pinning the tab cannot be done directly, but these methods might help:

1. Automatic pinning based on URL: [URL Pinner Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/url-pinner/lchefjdnocignejmkklgakfmnjhiimjh)
2. Obtain a shortcut for pinning: [Ferro extension](http://www.getferro.com/) - `Alt-Shift-P`